# New to Javascript, how do I pass an object into a constructor?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I am writing a program in Python but a small section needs to make use of a Google API function only available in Javascript so I'm trying to piece things together.

```
var swl = new google.maps.LatLng({lat: 55.857128, lng: -4.272051});
var nel = new google.maps.LatLng({lat: 55.867147, lng: -4.245272});
var boundsRectangle = new google.maps.LatLngBounds({sw:swl, ne:nel});
window.alert(boundsRectangle.getNorthEast());
```

There seems to be some issue in line 3. I have tried printing swl.lat() for example and that works so swl and nel seem to be fine but the window.alert is never created so it seems to be breaking there.

For the 3rd line Google says the LatLngBounds class has a constructor:

```
LatLngBounds(sw?:LatLng, ne?:LatLng)
```

where LatLng are objects. So I am assuming I just formatted this wrong - "LatLngBounds({sw:swl, ne:nel})" ?

Comment: Perhaps it should just be `.LatLngBounds(swl, nel)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`new google.maps.LatLngBounds` doesn't take an object as it's parameters, it takes two `google.maps.LatLng` objects. Read @Pointy. Also LatLng doesn't take objects, it takes two float values.

```
 var boundsRectangle = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
 new google.maps.LatLng(55.857128, -4.272051),
 new google.maps.LatLng(55.867147, -4.245272)
 );
```